# In code footer goes all over the place

Tags: html, css, footer

I have some troubles with my footer on a website. Footer is not displaying at the bottom of the page but it starts right below the header and covers elements that are under it. For better understanding I made [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4yVqE/) for it and [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u8xep862t65xqdh/%C4%8Dudn.JPG)

But its like this:

```
    <div class="mens">    
    <div class="main">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="section group">
                <div class="cont span_2_of_3">
                    <h2 class="head">PRIPOROČAMO</h2>
                        <div class="top-box">
```

and then there are some products and then there are the end divs for this:

```
                            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

And then follows the footer:

```
            <footer class="footer-2 bg-midnight-blue">
            <div class="container">
                <nav class="pull-left">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Company</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Blog</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="social-btns pull-right">
                    <a href="#"><div class="fui-vimeo"></div><div class="fui-vimeo"></div></a>
                    <a href="#"><div class="fui-facebook"></div><div class="fui-facebook"></div></a>
                    <a href="#"><div class="fui-twitter"></div><div class="fui-twitter"></div></a>
                </div>
                <div class="additional-links">
                    Be sure to take a look to our <a href="#">Terms of Use</a> and <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
```

And I know its a lot of code but I would really appreciate  if someone could look at it. Thanks.

Comment: You're going to need to _try_ to explain what the problem is. We have less idea than you do, we can't just guess what you feel is wrong with some random code

Comment: Okay sorry haha so the footer doesn't start at the bottom of the page like it should but ir starts at the start of page, theres header and than footer and under the footer there are objects that should be you know, there but are not, you can see how it looks like in jsfiddle link that I posted but here it is again: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4yVqE/) @Clive

Comment: And heres the screenshot: [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u8xep862t65xqdh/%C4%8Dudn.JPG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this to reset ur css

```
.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{content: '.';display: block;overflow: hidden;visibility: hidden;font-size: 0;line-height: 0;width: 0;height: 0;clear: both;}
.clearfix {overflow: auto;zoom: 1;}
```

and add clearfix class in parent div where in child u have used float like in

```
<div class="page-wrapper clearfix">
<div class="main clearfix">
<footer class="footer-2 bg-midnight-blue  clearfix">
```

Comment: Where shuld I put css? @aashi

Comment: @jaka_music you have written /*reset*/ css in that